# Swift Accessing UIButton Tags

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout

I created multiple buttons with unique tags and added the buttons to the UIView of my project. I want to re-access them so I can add the buttons into a views dictionary for autolayout.

```
func createButtons() {
    for index in 0...10 {
        var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        button.tag = index
        self.view.addSubview(button)
 }
```

Code to create a views dictionary for autolayout purposes.

```
func createDictionary() {
    var mbd : [String:UIButton]! = [:]

    for index in 0...10 {
        let tmpButton = self.view.viewWithTag(index) as? UIButton
        mbd["button" + String(index)] = tmpButton
    }
    return mbd
}
```

However, I don't think the above code is creating any dictionary and I am not sure why. If I shift the code which I append to the dictionary in the first `for loop` then everything works. But I am trying to learn to use the `viewWithTag` method as I will need it frequently.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: `viewWithTag` can be evil, especially when you use `0` as the first value because `0` is the default value for ALL views...

Comment: what is a better way to keep track of the buttons then?

Comment: Start with a unique index which greater than 0. Also, your code is not clear. You create a variable `buttonsDictionary` which is never used again in that function. Instead you use `mbd` (is it a class variable?) which is also returned from that function...

Comment: sorry about that, that is a typo. So unique index from `1` but still using `viewWithTag` is okay?

Comment: It's ok if it is unique and not 0

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need the tags for anything else, except for creating the dictionary, you could create the dictionary while you create the buttons.

I would suggest something like this:

```
func createButtons (){
    var mbd : [String:UIButton]! = [:]
    for index in 0...10 {
       var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
       self.view.addSubview(button)
       mbd["button" + String(index)] = button
    }
}
```

This solution is also more performant, in the sense that you don't call the loop twice and, since you already have the buttons, you don't need to call `viewWithTag` anymore.

Hope this works for you. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: unfortunately I will need to re-access the buttons later on in other functions.

Comment: You can still add the tags, just (index+1)*100, or something like that. Or you can keep the dictionary (set it as a property) and retrieve the buttons from there, when you need them